# Linq Expressions. Equivalent of greater than for strings

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression, linq-expressions

I have followed several threads on SO and other websites and am still having difficulty.

I have the following code:

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> Between<TSource, TKey>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector, TKey low, TKey high, bool inclusive = true) where TKey : IComparable<TKey>
    {
        var key = Expression.Invoke(keySelector, keySelector.Parameters.ToArray());

        var intLow = int.Parse(low.ToString());
        var intHigh = int.Parse(high.ToString());

        var lowerBound = (inclusive)
                  ? Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(key, Expression.Constant(intLow, typeof(int)))
                  : Expression.GreaterThan(key, Expression.Constant(intLow, typeof(int)));

        var upperBound = (inclusive)
                  ? Expression.LessThanOrEqual(key, Expression.Constant(intHigh, typeof(int)))
                  : Expression.LessThan(key, Expression.Constant(intHigh, typeof(int)));

        var and = Expression.AndAlso(lowerBound, upperBound);
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(
                        and, keySelector.Parameters);

        return source.Where(lambda);
    }
```

If I call this function with the following code:

```
lowValue = 2;
highValue = 11;

var sampleData = BuildSampleEntityInt(1, 3, 10, 11, 12, 15);
var query = sampleData.Between(s => s.SampleSearchKey, lowValue, highValue, false);
Assert.AreEqual(2, query.Count());
```

It works. But If I use Strings instead like:

```
lowValueString = "3";
highValueString = "10";

var sampleData = BuildSampleEntityString(1, 3, 10, 11, 12, 15);
var query = sampleData.Between(s => s.SampleSearchKey, lowValueString , highValueString);
Assert.AreEqual(2, query.Count());
```

or convert the strings to integers first

```
lowValueString = "3";
highValueString = "10";
int.TryParse(lowValueString, out lowValue);
int.TryParse(highValueString, out highValue);


var sampleData = BuildSampleEntityString(1, 3, 10, 11, 12, 15);
var query = sampleData.Between(s => s.SampleSearchKey, lowValue, highValue);
Assert.AreEqual(2, query.Count());
```

I get the following error:

> {"The binary operator GreaterThanOrEqual is not defined for the types
>   'System.String' and 'System.Int32'."}

When the following line runs.

```
var lowerBound = (inclusive)
             ? Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(key, Expression.Constant(intLow, typeof(int)))
             : Expression.GreaterThan(key, Expression.Constant(intLow, typeof(int)));
```

Can anyone point out what needs to be changed?

I have added the following:

```
 private IQueryable<SampleEntityInt> BuildSampleEntityInt(params int[] values)
    {
        return values.Select(
               value =>
               new SampleEntityInt() { SampleSearchKey = value }).AsQueryable();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for everyone looking, found the issue........I you look closely at the code you will notice that when the sample data is created two different functions are used. One creates int[] whilst the other creates string[]. Changed them both to be int[] and now ok.

Comment: This did not fix the problem

Comment: is there a reason why you build it with expressions instead of using simple lambdas?

Comment: Wait... your data is numbers... Why do you need to be able to compare the numbers to strings?

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that you define two generic type attributes: `TSource` and `TKey`, but actually you have three types of them.  It works, if `TKey` is the same type as `lowValue` and `highValue` (both are `int`), but it doesn't work if `lowValue` and `highValue` are of the type `string` and TKey is still `int`.

Code you provided works fine, if i add the third generic parameter `TLowHigh`, that's a type of your low/hight arguments :

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> Between<TSource, TKey, TLowHigh>(
      this IQueryable<TSource> source, 
      Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector, 
      TLowHigh low, 
      TLowHigh high,
      bool inclusive = true) 
          where TKey : IComparable<TKey>
{
    var key = Expression.Invoke(keySelector, keySelector.Parameters.ToArray());

    var intLow = int.Parse(low.ToString());
    var intHigh = int.Parse(high.ToString());

    var lowerBound = (inclusive)
            ? Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(key, Expression.Constant(intLow, typeof(int)))
            : Expression.GreaterThan(key, Expression.Constant(intLow, typeof(int)));

    var upperBound = (inclusive)
            ? Expression.LessThanOrEqual(key, Expression.Constant(intHigh, typeof(int)))
            : Expression.LessThan(key, Expression.Constant(intHigh, typeof(int)));

    var and = Expression.AndAlso(lowerBound, upperBound);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(
                    and, keySelector.Parameters);

    return source.Where(lambda);
}
```